# Compare one-hot-encoded column header and predicted labels

Tags: pandas, boolean, one-hot-encoding

I have 3 one-hot-encoded columns where the header names are labels, and one prediction column `preds` where the labels are predicted (see image). I want to calculate the performance of my predictions by comparing the label in `preds` and the 1-encoded column header.

[image: see here]

In this example I only have 20% predicted correctly.

Is there a quick way of doing this in pandas?

Comment: please check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)  and [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

```
df[['Type_1','Type_2','Type_3']].lookup(df.index, df['preds']).mean() * 100
```